# store creates duplicate data in case of mapping

Tags: extjs, model, mapping, store, extjs5

If data supplied is mapped then store creates duplicate data (Ext v 5.1.0)

I use a store that loads a dummy json, but the records are duplicated, containing both mapped and field names.

Basically I have an application in ExtJs 4, where it is working properly and after migration to v5.1.0 I encountered this issue.
Someone has any hints?

Thank you

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/j71

[image]

```
Ext.define('My.Model', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    idProperty: 'EventId',
    fields: [
        {
            mapping: 'id',
            name: 'EventId',
            type: 'int'
        },{
            mapping: 'title',
            name: 'Title',
            type: 'string'
        }
    ],
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'events',
            totalProperty: 'count'
        },
        writer: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'events',
            writeAllFields: true,
            encode: true,
            nameProperty: 'name'
        }
    }
}); 

Ext.define('My.Store', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'My.Model',
    autoLoad: true,
     proxy: {
        api: {
            read: 'http://localhost/dummy/data/json.php'
        },
        type: 'ajax',
        enablePaging: true,
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'events',
            totalProperty: 'count'
        },
        writer: {
            type: 'json',
            allowSingle: false,
            writeAllFields: true,
            nameProperty: 'name'
        }
    }
    listeners: {
        load: function(store, records, successful){
            Ext.each(records, function(rec){
                console.log(rec.data);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the choice, I would change how the data is returned but for many reasons this probably is not possible (the reason you want to map the data instead!).

You do have some options to change the data as it comes in, but none are really that great and I haven't looked into the performance implications.

A.) On an the individual fields, wipe out the less desirable field via the `convert` config:

```
{
     //mapping: 'notes',
     name: 'Notes',
     convert: function(value, record){
         var value = record.data.notes;
         record.data.notes = undefined;
         return value;
     },
     type: 'string'
 }
```

B.) Use the [reader transform method](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.reader.Json-cfg-transform).

```
transform: function(data, request) {
             // do some manipulation of the unserialized data object
             for(var i = 0, len = data.events.length; i < len; i++){
                 // convert data.events[i] to your specs
             }
             return data;
         }
```